# how to unpack a system.string data type into a flat string in kql

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

The schema shows that a field is a "system.string" and it has a variable number of elements, like a list of lists. What I would like to do is convert this into a normal string and store that in a field. Just tostring() does not cut it. It is like I have to unpack and then concatenate. How can I do this? You could reference each element with Tags[0], Tags[1].... but there is a variable number of indexes.

example: How can one expland MoreData into a flat string?

```
datatable(Date:datetime, Event:string, MoreData:dynamic) [
datetime(1910-06-11), "Born", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
datetime(1930-01-01), "Enters Ecole Navale", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
datetime(1953-01-01), "Published first book", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
datetime(1997-06-25), "Died", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
]
```

Suppose you wanted to generate a result of '"value5", "value6"' as a string?

Comment: Please add a data sample, using datatable

Comment: I added an example that closely relates to the predicament

Comment: O.K. now I'm confused regarding the desired result :-)

Comment: My bad. The issue I have got is that the input data is a list of tags and I want to apply a regex to extract them. In the present form, (system.string/list of lists) the output generates additional back stroke characters.  // I made a change to the table and what the output needs to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(Date:datetime, Event:string, MoreData:dynamic) [
datetime(1910-06-11), "Born", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
datetime(1930-01-01), "Enters Ecole Navale", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
datetime(1953-01-01), "Published first book", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
datetime(1997-06-25), "Died", dynamic(["value5", "value6"]),
]
| extend result = array_strcat(MoreData,',')
```

| Date | Event | MoreData | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1910-06-11T00:00:00Z | Born | ["value5","value6"] | value5,value6 |
| 1930-01-01T00:00:00Z | Enters Ecole Navale | ["value5","value6"] | value5,value6 |
| 1953-01-01T00:00:00Z | Published first book | ["value5","value6"] | value5,value6 |
| 1997-06-25T00:00:00Z | Died | ["value5","value6"] | value5,value6 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WQQQvCMAyF74L/IeziBhWsMsWBF3FHxbuIZGvUYm2hzUTBH2%20HinhTEkII73uQp5BjVYbSBTIVKg7WZxJQXshyEdhrexCwdJ6iAAt1s3jWdQabbuctTuVUDvqDcV/KTEAyd94mAl7KdJNc0DSUx9NzGyfbTHzRo0jL2C1dWiYfoKydIVhhJOg/s3z0MVs3ldHhSAr22geGyrnTf27TSfvYMG/dFprUD/S227kDXZmsAk%20hMQwzQO/xtotx1sjpO03RE73sAZnIhTyCAQAA)